# Umbraco: how to create nested categories?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I'm pretty new to Umbraco but I need an answer from someone else more expert than me. I need to creare a sort of hierarchy, something like:

CATALOG > FIRST LEVEL (1...n) > SECOND LEVEL (1...n) > PRODUCT

From the basics I would create a documentType for the product (last item) and something else for each level. Would be enough another documentType? the use of tags might be useful?

Answer (score 4):

If you are sure that you have only 100% sure that there is only one subcategory, you could create docTypes for each level:

- catalog

  - category
  - category

    - subcategory

      - product
      - product

If you really have nesting categories, then create just one category document type and allow the same category document type as child node (in the structure tab).

- catalog

  - category

    - category
    - category
    - category

      - category
        ...

        - product

From a programming perspective, you don't have much more work with the second option, while allowing the user to decide and play with the categories much more freely.

Remember if all these pages are also webpages, start with a "master" or "webpage" document type where you put all shared properties (fields) on.

Comment: Thanks for reply Dampee. This approach fits my requirements. Somebody else also suggested me to use a TAG classification in order to create a hierarchy. Basically with two DocumentType, one for product and the last for each category, I might be able to achieve my task.